# How do I know if this is a weak entity?

Tags: database

Customers have multiple addresses. An address is identified by an id number in addition to the customer’s reference. **Each address should have a type, which indicates its usage**. For example, address types could be: Shipping Address, Company Address, Primary Address, etc. Each address type is identified by a unique reference and should have a description.

Is the address type in this case a weak entity? Making the Address the strong entity. The formulation here is that, if an **address type** can exist without the **Address** itself.

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: address types are not large datasets. So use as a weak entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concepts like weak entity are tools to help you design your database.  In this instance, I think the key distinction on whether address type is a weak entity is whether an address type ends up belonging to an address, or whether it ends up being shared among a lot of addresses.  (That's slightly different from whether it's a weak entity, but I think that will likely be the major practical effect of the distinction, and it's a lot easier to reason about)

If you have a small number of address types across your application, then address type is probably not a weak entity, and address types are probably shared among lots of addresses.

If instead, someone inputs an address type with an address or set of addresses, and you'll have a lot of them, then address type is probably a weak entity, and it's reasonably probable that it is best that it belong to address.

Only someone who is looking at how you plan to use addresses can decide which is going on in your application.